# Python Requests and LDAP Authentication

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests

Is there any way to using LDAP for authentication in python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)?

```
requests.get(url, auth='LDAP Authentication')
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special authentication frameworks require custom authentication handlers. There may well be an LDAP Authentication Handler already built for requests, or there [may not](https://pypi.org/search/?q=requests+ldap). Luckily there's documentation for writing the handler for Requests [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-authentication)